# chrome extension licensing api/payment stuff

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

When we are performing a request to get info about userlicense, we get an object which contains some properties.

The one which I am interested in is the "createdTime" property.

I don't want to wait a whole month just to see what might happen. I need to know if the "createdTime" property will change the next month (once the user pays another monthly fee), so we can say that each next month we have a "new license". Or is the license object always remain the same? And "createdTime" will not change even in a couple of months?

Also, does the user gets charged automatically each month (if we go with monthly payments)? Or once the license has expired, he must pay for it again?

Thanks in advance, any help would be appreciated much.

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/userLicenses/getUserLicense), the `"createdTime"` property means that the creation time of the license. And it is formatted as a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). You can read more information [here](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/one_time_payments) about chrome web store licensing API.

Comment: That's understandable. I mean, will the createdTime property update and the license would be treated as a new one, when the paid month ends and the next paid month starts. Or if the license always remains the same, no matter how much time passed from the "purchase".

Comment: Hi @yegorchik I've the same question related createdTime, did you find answer for your question?